# Tile an A6 PDF so that it fits into A4 perfectly

Tags: pdf, scribus

I am using Scribus to produce an invitation. The invitation is A6 in size, and I would like to tile the document so that it fits 4 times onto A4, thus maximising my printer! I can then cut out the A6 invitations from the A4 page.

I've found the command pdfposter (I'm on Ubuntu), but I'm not sure that will do the trick...

Any hints, pointers, ideas or scripts out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `pdfnup` program from the [PDFjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic/firth/software/pdfjam) suite (which is [packaged](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/pdfjam) for Ubuntu). If you have the original pages in a document containing multiple A6-sized papers named `a6.pdf`, the following command should do the job of arranging four original pages per one A4 page:

```
pdfnup --nup 2x2 --no-landscape --paper a4paper --noautoscale true --outfile a4.pdf a6.pdf
```

If you need to create the source file by repeating a single original page four times, the `pdfjoin` program from the same package will help you there:

```
pdfjoin --outfile a6.pdf original.pdf original.pdf original.pdf original.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) allows you to tile a PDF *at time of printing*. You won't need to modify the original file.

**Edit**:

If you want to create a new PDF containing the tiled pages you can use Acrobat Reader to print back to a PDF writer such as Adobe Acrobat or [CutePDF Writer](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp).

Comment: Thanks. I should have said that I wanted to avoid this option as the person doing the printing isn't very technical! Giving him an A4 pdf to print is a lot safer...  :-)

Comment: Ah, I see. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. In order for me to get the same A6 page displayed into 4, equal sized quadrants, on a single A4, I had to use the `pdfnup` command with multiple `a6.pdf` arguments. e.g. 
`pdfnup --nup 2x2 --no-landscape --paper a4paper --noautoscale true --outfile a4.pdf a6.pdf a6.pdf a6.pdf a6.pdf`

The other command with `pdfjoin` also didn't produce the desired results.

Comment: What does this do exactly for the end result since you say for a different effect?

Comment: You say that this produces a different effect, but what is it? Why would somebody choose this answer over the others?

Comment: Edited the answer to make it clearer what I meant